# Having a Linux server with key pair and ssh private key. Ppk in Windows desktop application for server login

Tags: unix, ssh, windows

I have a Windows desktop application from  where I need to login Linux server for accessing a configuration file from server. Hardcoding the Linux username and password in my code will not be a gud idea.  So having a private key in my local and adding the same key to Linux server authorised keys and providing read access only to the specific config File for one user.  (no access to other files in Linux server for that particular user) would this be a right idea with respect security purposes??..  Or any idea how to login Linux server from windows application securely.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  All we know at present is that you want to access a "config" file in your windows app, and that this app is on a linux server. Is this file the same for all users of the windows app?  Is this file dynamic?  How often does it change?  What does the app do with the config file?  What information does it contain and how does the app use that information?  There are many ways to make that file available, and I'm not sure if ssh is better than making the file available via http.  You can use libssh2 to do scp operations... see https://www.libssh2.org/examples/scp.html

Answer (score 1):

scp  is built to do this already as part of ssh.

Winscp is a well known free scp client for windows that already has features to script and automate transfers.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

So yes, create a user that has access to the config file.

Create a key pair and add the pub key to an .ssh directory you create in the user's home directory.  Perms for the directory and file need to be owner only.

As you mentioned pub key needs to be renamed to authorized_keys.

Make sure you convert the key appropriately for the os.

Openssh and putty keys are in different formats but there are tools for each that will let you convert one format to another.

On your windows machine you need the private key, not the public.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation.. !! As u said I came across winscp.. But here the scenario is I don't want to copy any file rather I have to read only the config file from server. So handling server login from my application through key pair would be a proper solution with respect to security concerns??? Or it would be a violation..... ??? Please suggest if you have any other ideas as well

Comment: Corrected my question as you said it should be private key in local not public..  ****

Comment: You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can track your login security constantly with Data Leak Detection tools. I use [Hivecode](https://hivecode.io) for this purpose. It helps to know for sure if anybody else has access to your server and to your digital assets. I was already notified once and I've got all the information about the theft of my source code.